# Como hago para que no me rompa el diseño las columnas? Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, bootstrap

estoy iniciando con bootstrap 3 y tengo un diseño creado en el cual traigo productos de una base de datos, el problema es que al redimencionar con las clases col-sm-3 las columnas se achican pero los nombres interfieren en que se cree un espacio debajo de las cajas que no coincide con la linea de diseño, desplazando las otras cajas y dejando espacio en blanco

[image: Imagen de como se ve con los cambios]

Comment: Agrega tu codigo al post, la imagen es solo referencia.

Comment: Ahora subo no me di cuenta